# When can you uniquely determine a square matrix if you know the sum of its rows and columns?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices

There is a square matrix consisted of only $0, 1, i$. You know the sum of all the numbers in each row and each column. When can you uniquely determine the matrix?

Edit: For clarification, there is a n times n gird, and Alice writes either $0, 1,$ or $i$ in each square, and tells Bob only the sum of each row and each column. We want to find all possible ways Alice can fill the grid, so that Bob can determine how she filled it.

Comment: Have you considered the matrices $\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}$ and $\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}$?

Comment: Yes we've considered that. Using the fact that those two matrices can't exist, we've solved the problem for when the matrix is filled with only 0,1.

Comment: What do you mean by "those two matrices cannot exist"?  If your problem setting has additional constraints, please tell us.

Comment: What we mean by 'those two matrices don't exist" is that if one of those two exist, than we can exchange each other, which means that the matrix cannot be uniquely determined.

Comment: Oh, do you mean this: Let $r_1, ..., r_n$ be the row sums and $c_1, ..., c_n$ be the column sums.  For what $2n$-tuple $(r_1, ..., r_n, c_1, ..., c_n)$ is there a unique binary-matrix satisfying those sums?

Comment: Ah yes, that's exactly what I mean

Comment: Wait...  Did you just change the question? I dont remember seeing $i$ before.  Is this $i = \sqrt{-1}$?  So these are no longer binary matrices?

Answer (score 0):

Clearly if one of the dimensions is $1$ you can do it.  The examples given show that $2 \times 2$ does not work.  For any larger dimension, you have fewer equations (row and column sums) than unknowns (elements in the matrix), so you should not expect a unique solution.  The $2 \times 2$ example demonstrates this.  In any larger matrix, fill everything except the upper left $2 \times 2$ block and fill the block with the identity.  Compute the row and column sums.  The row and column sums will be the same with the other $2 \times 2$ block.

Comment: I think you've kinda misunderstood what we meant. I'll explain the situation with an example. There is a n times n gird, and Alice writes either 0, 1, or i in each square, and tells Bob only the sum of each row and each column. We want to find all possible ways Alice can fill the gird, so that Bob can determine how she filled it.